# Element li not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Tags: php, css, wordpress, plugins, widget

I am currently developing a website,..When  validate the site using validator.w3, it has this kind of error:

```
Element li not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
…widget-2" class="widget Social_Widget"><div class="socialmedia-buttons smw_lef…
Contexts in which element li may be used:
Inside ol elements.
Inside ul elements.
Inside menu elements whose type attribute is in the toolbar state.
Content model for element div:
Flow content.
```

I found a social media widget plug in installed on it..but I cant find where is it specifically located , i found the social-widget.php but still cant find this line:

```
<li id="social-widget-2" class="widget Social_Widget"><div class="socialmedia-buttons smw_left"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/JustSimplyOutsourcingWorldwideInc" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><img width="32" height="32" src="http://www.justsimplyoutsourcingworldwide.com/wp-content/plugins/social-media-widget/images/default/32/facebook.png"
alt=" Facebook"
title=" Facebook" style="opacity: 0.8; -moz-opacity: 0.8;" class="fade" /></a><a href="https://plus.google.com/b/100887468338831289783/100887468338831289783/posts" rel="publisher" target="_blank"><img width="32" height="32" src="http://www.justsimplyoutsourcingworldwide.com/wp-content/plugins/social-media-widget/images/default/32/googleplus.png"
alt=" Google+"
title=" Google+" style="opacity: 0.8; -moz-opacity: 0.8;" class="fade" /></a><a href="https://twitter.com/JSOWorldwide" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><img width="32" height="32" src="http://www.justsimplyoutsourcingworldwide.com/wp-content/plugins/social-media-widget/images/default/32/twitter.png"
alt=" Twitter"
title=" Twitter" style="opacity: 0.8; -moz-opacity: 0.8;" class="fade" /></a><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/just-simply-outsourcing" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><img width="32" height="32" src="http://www.justsimplyoutsourcingworldwide.com/wp-content/plugins/social-media-widget/images/default/32/linkedin.png"
alt=" LinkedIn"
title=" LinkedIn" style="opacity: 0.8; -moz-opacity: 0.8;" class="fade" /></a><a href="http://instagram.com/jsoworldwide/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><img width="32" height="32" src="http://www.justsimplyoutsourcingworldwide.com/wp-content/plugins/social-media-widget/images/default/32/instagram.png"
alt=" Instagram"
title=" Instagram" style="opacity: 0.8; -moz-opacity: 0.8;" class="fade" /></a><a href="http://pinterest.com/jsoworldwide/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><img width="32" height="32" src="http://www.justsimplyoutsourcingworldwide.com/wp-content/plugins/social-media-widget/images/default/32/pinterest.png"
alt=" Pinterest"
title=" Pinterest" style="opacity: 0.8; -moz-opacity: 0.8;" class="fade" /></a><a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/JSOutsourcingWw" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><img width="32" height="32" src="http://www.justsimplyoutsourcingworldwide.com/wp-content/plugins/social-media-widget/images/default/32/youtube.png"
alt=" YouTube"
title=" YouTube" style="opacity: 0.8; -moz-opacity: 0.8;" class="fade" /></a></div></li>
```

this code is seen through inspecting the element.. I need to find that line but i cant find it in the social-widget.php..please help

Comment: What is parent element of your li ?

Comment: Can you post the code of the social-widget.php?

Comment: try adding before and after widget option

Comment: It seems that the ul tag is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to error message I guess you use li tag inside a div tag which is wrong, review your code carefully

**You try to do this**

```
   <div>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
   </div>
```

**li must be inside `ol` or `ul` tag**

```
   <div>
        <ol>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ol>
   </div>
```

Comment: I cant find the li ,the ol, nd that div.. I'm using the social widget plug in.cant paste he social-widget.php its too long..please help.. :(